# Можно ли сжать форму ввода данных пользователем?

Tags: python, input, итераторы

Всем привет, сайт использую впервые не судите строго =).

Например у нас есть задача: Просто считать ввод данных пользователем до тех пор пока не будет введена строка **'555'** - я всё время оформляю это таким образом:

```
Answer = list()
while True:
    s = input()
    if s == '555':
        break
    Answer.append(s)
```

Но что то мне подсказывает что можно делать это намного проще.
Недавно положил глаз на функцию **iter()**, потому что второй аргумент у неё - остановочный, но у меня до сих пор наблюдаются проблемы с её использованием, я подозреваю что она может быть ключом к решению, но сам я не могу его разгадать.

Решил написать сюда, может быть кто-нибудь из вас сможет помочь сжать этот код до 1-3 строчек, я буду вам очень благодарен =)

Прошу, можете использовать любые встроенные функции в Python, но пожалуйста - **не используйте не встроенные по стандарту библиотеки** (Если решения через таковые имеются)

Comment: Нужно что бы код занимал меньше строк =)
Для чего сжимать? Мне стало интересно, можно ли это вообще как либо сделать.

Comment: Спасибо большое mrEvgenX за решение этого вопроса, очень нравится это решение =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, с помощью `iter` можно сократить:

```
Answer = [s for s in iter(input, '555')]
```

Полезная ссылка:

- https://docs-python.ru/tutorial/vstroennye-funktsii-interpretatora-python/funktsija-iter/

Comment: Ещё короче: `list(iter(input, '555'))`.

Answer (score 1):

```
Answer = list()
while  (s := input()) != '555' and not Answer.append(s): pass
print(Answer)
```

Работает для python версии 3.8 и выше